# Excel formula to conditional rank on three criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to achieve the following with an excel formula;

Ranking Col A (e.g. if QLD) against Col C and then Col B (the lower the number in either Col B or Col C the lower the ranking).
I need this to only ranking e.g. QLD against other QLD results.
[image]

I have been playing with variations of this formula but cannot get the desired result.

```
=COUNTIF($C$5:$C$11,">"&C5)+1+SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$11=A5)*($B$5:$B$11>B5))
```

Comment: What do you mean by ranking? `Col D` is your desired result?

Comment: Does this do what you want? `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,">"&C2)+COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,C2,B$2:B$11,">"&B2)+1`

Comment: @Harun24HR I think I figured it out. QLD has two results. They are in rows 1 and 8. The one in row 8 has the highest score (B + C) and is ranked first for that reason. The result in row 1 ranks 2nd. This seems to work out for all the figures in column D which, therefore, should indeed be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I used the formula as suggested by Jerry. It did exactly what I needed.

Formula used below:
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,">"&C2)+COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,C2,B$2:B$11,">"&B2)+1